# Page numbering affected by recursive programming

Tags: page-numbering, date, recursion, advdate, compare

I asked this question [How to do recursive program with latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472544/how-to-do-recursive-program-with-latex) and got the following excellent answer by @JosephWright

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{advdate}

% Set the first practice date
\ThisDay{7}
\ThisMonth{2}
\ThisYear{2019}

%... the number of days between lectures
\newcommand*{\lecturegap}{7}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{holiday}
\newcommand*\addholiday[3]{%
  \stepcounter{holiday}%
  \@namedef{holiday\arabic{holiday}}{%
    \def\holidayDay{#1}%
    \def\holidayMonth{#2}%
    \def\holidayYear{#3}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\holidayDay}{0}
\newcommand*{\holidayMonth}{0}
\newcommand*{\holidayYear}{0}
\addholiday{3}{3}{2019}  % ter Carnaval
\addholiday{18}{4}{2019} % qui Atividade complementar
\addholiday{19}{4}{2019} % sex Santa
\addholiday{21}{4}{2019} % dom Tiradentes/Páscoa
\addholiday{1}{5}{2019}  % qua Trabalhador
\addholiday{19}{6}{2019} % qua Aniv. Rib. Preto

\newif\ifholiday
\newcommand*{\groupA}{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\nextprac}{%
  \holidayfalse
  \count0=1 %
  \loop
    \ifnum\count0>\value{holiday}\else
      \@nameuse{holiday\number\count0 }%
      \ifnum 0%
        \ifnum\holidayDay=\day1\else0\fi
        \ifnum\holidayMonth=\month1\else0\fi
        \ifnum\holidayYear=\year1\else0\fi
        =111 %
        \holidaytrue
        \count0=\value{holiday}%
        \else
      \fi
    \advance\count0 by 1 %
  \repeat
  \ifholiday
    \AdvanceDate[\lecturegap]%
    \expandafter\nextprac
  \else
    \ifx\groupA\empty
      \edef\groupA{%
        {\day=\the\day\month=\the\month\year=\the\year\relax\noexpand\today}}%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\nextprac
    \else
      \AdvanceDate[\lecturegap]%
      \section*{\groupA\space$\parallel$ \today}%
      \def\groupA{}%
      \AdvanceDate[\lecturegap]%
    \fi
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

  \nextprac
  Practice one

  \nextprac
  Practice two

  \nextprac
  Practice three

  \nextprac
  Practice four

  \nextprac
  Practice five

  \nextprac
  Practice six

  \nextprac
  Practice seven

  \nextprac
  Practice eight

  \nextprac
  Practice nine

  \nextprac
  Practice ten

\end{document}
```

However, a few months latter, I realized that this code affects page numbering. But I cannot figure out how it is affected nor how to fix it.

The only thing I realized is that the page number becomes the exact number of holidays created by `\addholiday` command.

My question is: **how to restore page numbering without leaving the presented code away?**

Comment: `\count0` refers to the page number.

Comment: @JosephWright should stick to expl3 then he wouldn't using \count0 as loop variable ;-) (he probably wanted to use \count@)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `\count0` in the wild, which contains the page number.

Change all occurrences of `\count0` into `\@tempcnta`